# Import dump/sql file into my postgresql database on Linode

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, vps, linode

I recently moved my Ruby on Rails 4 app from Heroku to Linode. Everything has been setup correctly, but I need to populate my database with a file, lets call it movies.sql

I am not very familiar with postgresql command and VPS, so having trouble getting this done. I uploaded it to Dropbox since I saw many SO posts that you can use S3/Dropbox.

I saw different commands like this (unsure how to go about it in my situation):

1. `psql -U postgres -d testdb -f /home/you/file.sql`
2. `psql -f file.sql dbname`
3. `psql -U username -d myDataBase -a -f myInsertFile`

So which is the correct one in my situation and how to run when I SSH in Linode? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to get the file onto your server or you'll need to use a different command from your terminal.

If you have the file locally, you can restore without sshing in using the psql command:

```
psql -h <user@ip_address_of_server> -U <database_username> -d <name_of_the_database> -f local/path/to/your/file.sql
```

Otherwise, the command is:

```
psql -U <database_username> -d <name_of_the_database> < remote/path/to/your/file.sql
```

`-U` sets the db username, `-h` sets the host, `-d` sets the name of the database, and `-f` tells the command you're restoring from a file.

Comment: The second version of the command is missing the `-f` flag before the file name